# What is best approach for setting up internet gateway from orange pi running Raspbian

Tags: linux, networking, routing, raspbian, iot

I have cheap IoT device from Orangepi running raspbian server with wlan0 and ppp0 interfaces. wlan0 will be connected to access point in the local network. the ppp0 interface will be connected to GSM network through /dev/modem0 and provide internet access for the device.

1. want orangePi to be able to connect internet itself through ppp0
2. want all devices in the local network that will be connected to router/access point be able to connect to the internet through IoT ppp0 interface
3. also want to be able to setup port forwarding from ppp0 interface to some devices in the local network

What will be the best approach to do it and how to configure IoT Linux box?

Comment: 5 years later this orangepi 2g is peace of ### :D

Answer (score 0):

On th highest level, orange pi will act as an Internet gateway for your network.
Basically you need to configure orange pe as an router, the most common is to use NAT for this.

LAN --- WIFI --- OrangePI --- PPP --- GSM

so you need to find out the following:

how to configure your GSM for raspbian - I'd suggest to look this up according to your modem model.

How to configure NAT between WAN and PPP (this is described for many distros and should be same for this one).

How to make port forwarding in Linux (described in many howtos too).

Network devices accessing to the internet via Orange pi will have to be able to reach orange pi's wifi's ip address.

Network devices accessing to the internet via Orange pi will need to have orange pi's wifi's ip address set as gateway.

Answer (score 0):

So here's how I did it:

1. Turn off power management on Orange PI. Add following line to /etc/network/interfaces

   `iw dev wlan0 set power_save off`
2. Enable IP Forwarding. Add following line in /etc/sysctl.cong

   `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`
3. Enable NAT. Run following commands:

   `sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE`

   `sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o wlan0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT`

   `sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT`

and to permanently apply rules type this command

```
sudo sh -c "iptables-save > /etc/iptables.ipv4.nat"
```

and add following code to /etc/network/interfaces

```
up iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.ipv4.nat
```

4. Configure wvdial and test if it connects to GSM network. Create following script

   `#! /bin/bash
   (
     while : ; do
        wvdial
        sleep 10
     done
   ) &`

and add above script to be run in /etc/rc.local file.

Sources are:
virtono.com
elinux.org
wiki.archlinux.org

Comment: Thanks very thorough explanation, and 5 years late I can do it myself :)